# How can I best achieve a stable solution of Pt-Nanowires in water

Tags: aqueous-solution, synthesis, nanotechnology

I am synthesizing platinum nanowires ($50nm×20\mu m$) in aqueous solution. Unfortunately they start to aggregate rapidly, which is not desired.

How can I keep them dispersed?

Comment: I think there are several things that could work for you, but I suspect the driving issue in your choice will be whether the additive interferes with your process.  Could you state in a few sentences the gist of your process?